# How to improve my ios app performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, uiviewcontroller

Right now my app is very slow and heavy.
I would like to share with you my design to see if you have any improvement suggestions.

I have a main `UIViewController` that has in it a `UIButton` and a `UICollectionView` .
The `UICollectionView` holds an `NSArray` of 6 initialized  `UIViewController`'s .

The main `UIViewController` has delegate property and methods for each `UIViewController` in the  `UICollectionView` to listen .
Every time the `UIButton` is clicked it calls all his delegates and sends data so that evrey `UIViewController` can refresh its view . also all the data is written into the device `NSDocumentDirectory`. when the `UIButton` is pressed again the delegates stop reciveing data and all the data in the `NSDocumentDirectory` is sent to the user by email. But not deleted , the user has a choice to delete all his saved data.
[image]

P.S

I first used `UIPageController` , but i had a bug and decided to use `UICollectionView`.

Any suggestion of how to improve my app ?
If i use `UIView` inside the `UICollectionView` instead of `UIViewController` would it help ?

Comment: Have you used the Instruments tool to analyse your application performance and identify areas where a lot of time is spent?  Also it seems like you could improve things with a single data model object that was referenced by the view controllers and sending a NSNotification when the model changes rather than making many delegate calls

Comment: Which bug did you have with a `UIPageController`?

Comment: @Paulw11 no i haven't used the instrument tool, i will do that thank you,  is using NSNotification more efficient than delegates?

Comment: No difference. And sending notifications or calling delegates is very cheap, the work they are doing is what counts.

Comment: Using delegates isn't less efficient in terms of the amount of work done, but it does couple your classes more closely and requires more work to 1) keep track of all of the delegates and 2) invoke them all.  With a notification you simply fire it off and let all of the interested parties deal with it.

Comment: what do you meen by 'Invoke them all' ? @Paulw11

Comment: I mean that your main view controller has to keep track of the sub view controllers and then invoke a delegate method on each of them, presumably in a loop.  While each individual method call (possibly) won't take long, it is simpler to use publish/subscribe with NSNotification and avoid it altogether

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figure it out
,I was writing data to `NSDocumentDirectory` and i was doing it on the main thread, Big mistake i moved it into a background thread and it improved my app performance.
Thank you for your help.